# Telnet to public IP times out but doesn't when LAN address used

Tags: linux, networking, email, routing, telnet

I have a new email server and and old email server on my network.

I can send email to the new email server (let's call it mail.newmailserver.com) from Gmail and reply successfully (e.g. to/from works). I can send from mail.newmailserver.com to mail.oldmailserver.com successfully. I cannot send from mail.oldmailserver.com to mail.newmailserver.com. Logs on the mail.oldserver.com show a connection timeout.

When I am on mail.oldmailserver.com and issue this command:
telnet mail.newmailserver.com 25
the connection times out.

When I am on mailolderserver.com and issue this command:
telnet local IP of mail.newemailserver.com 25

I am connected.

Since Gmail works with mail.newmailserver.com, it must be something in my local network but I don't know how or where to start to debug this problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If the servers have "private/internal" IP addresses, search the site for "NAT hairpin".

Comment: The servers have a private internal IP address (both on the same LAN) and are 1:1 nat'ed with a public IP address. (e.g. there are two public IP addresses, one for each email server)

Comment: Thanks for helping me with NAT hairpin, @user1686. I wasn't familiar with that concept. I cannot see how to address that with the firewall I am using. Also, it is weird that I can send from the new email server to the old email server but not the other way around when they are both on the same network behind the same firewall.